# Take VMware VM State Home With Me

Tags: vmware-workstation

I work in VMs day in and day out, it's wonderful, encapsulating all the stuff I need for development in a contained unit.

My question is: I want to be able to take my VM home with me, the problem is the VM is 30GB, and it takes about 30 minutes to copy that much data to my external HDD.

Is it possible to somehow save the "state" of the VM, go home, and just resume it like a I would a laptop?

Oh... almost forgot, I use VMware Workstation 6.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMotion can do live migration however as far as I am aware state cannot be used to restore to VM's on two different servers. These snapshots are tightly bound to the orginal VM and I can foresee a lot of issues in even trying and corruption happening extremely quickly.

Can I suggest just running it from the external driver directly?

Comment: @Diago: that is what I'm doing. I'm using an External HDD ATM.  I'm just curious if it's possible, I guess it's not, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since a large chunk of your VM most likely never changes, you can use VMware Workstation to a linked clone, and just copy the clone VM each time.  A linked clone is a snapshot against an existing VM at a specific point in time, plus all the changes made since the snapshot was created.

Note, that the clone will gradually increase in size over time, due to Windows Updates and other software updates; so you may want to occasionally rebaseline your VMs--that is, bring the original VM up-to-date and copy your files onto it, stop using your existing linked clone, and create a new linked clone.